# Github Actions - Cypress

Tags: github, cypress, github-actions

I followed official [Cypress](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/continuous-integration/ci-provider-examples) documentation, and below I will attach my github workflow, but problem is it goes different way in my case. When actions run, Cypress starts downloading something, but it never ends (I waited 1.5 hour).

```
env:
  NODE_PATH: 'src/'
  #.. local env

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: self-hosted

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [ 14.x ]

    steps:

      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      - run: npm ci
      - name: Server start
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v2
        with:
          build: npm run build
          start: npm start
          spec: cypress/integration/*.js
        env:
          ELECTRON_ENABLE_STACK_DUMPING: 1
      - name: Exist check
          # Only runs if all of the files exists
        run: |
          if  [ -d "/..." ]
          then
            rm -r /...
            mv build /...
          fi
```

[image: GthubAction]

Comment: Please you `v2` here `uses: actions/setup-node@v1`

Comment: Thanks, but problem was old version of ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is old version of ubuntu. change version or mention it in yaml.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```yaml
jobs:
  cypress-run:
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
      # Install npm dependencies, cache them correctly
      # and run all Cypress tests
      - name: Cypress run
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v6
```

You can also read detailed instructions how to set up Cypress with Github Actions here - https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/cypress-with-github-actions/